# My Spotify App keeps crashing because it's always on Full screen

Tags: macos, crash, spotify

I have installed my Spotify app on my OSX 10.9.2 and I opened it with Full Screen mode. Somehow the app crashed and every time I open the app it always comes with Full Screen mode and keeps crashing. I deleted and reinstalled again a couple times already, but nothing works. Not sure how to solve this problem. Is there anyway I could completely delete the app on OSX and not just drag and drop to the Trash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you do not need to uninstall Spotify, but you may want to remove Spotify's settings.

1. Open Finder
2. Click **Go** in the menu bar
3. Press ⌥ and keep it down
4. A new item **Library** appears, click it
5. Release ⌥
6. Go to the folder **Preferences**
7. *Search* for **Spotify**
8. Instead of searching on *this machine*, search in **Preferences** (current folder)
9. Move or remove any Spotify related file to reset the preferences

If Spotify still doesn't work, repeat the same steps, but instead of Preferences, choose the **Application Support** folder. If it still doesn't work, search the entire **Library**.